# Where do you store the logic for a JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

I'm a little confused on where the action logic (what happens when a user selects a menu item from the popup) should be placed. Currently, I have it stored in a subclass of JPopupMenu, but it doesn't seem to call the event when I click on a menu item.

#### Subclass code:

```
public class MyPopupMenu extends JPopupMenu {
    JMenuItem item1;
    JMenuItem item2;
    
    public MyPopupMenu() {
        item1 = new JMenuItem("New Tab");
        item2 = new JMenuItem("Close Tab");
        
        add(item1);
        add(item2);
        
    }
    
    class myListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
            System.out.println("I've been clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

I attached this to my JTabbedPane by calling the `setComponentPopupMenu`method.

```
myTabPane.setComponentPopupMenu(myPopupMenu);
```

This compiles OK. And it does show the popup menu as expected, but upon selecting one of the menu options in the popup, all is silent. No message gets displayed. Do I need to put it somewhere else?

Comment: a) don't extend JPopupMenu b) don't use mouselisteners, instead use Actions (by simply adding them to the popup) BTW, that's all explained in the relevant chapter of the online tutorial reference in the swing tag wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have to add [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to [JMenuItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)
- add proper listener to use [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for [JMenuItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), read Oracle tutorial for working code example

Answer (score 0):

Add MouseListner to your menu item

```
myListener myListener = new myListener();
item1.addMouseListener(myListener);
item2.addMouseListener(myListener);
```

Seems your approach is bit wrong. Please refer [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)